# How to delete locked DNN search files in APP_Data > Search?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Our DNN is showing old search results.
I have looked at this URL on the DNN Forums: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/523345/scope/posts/search-results-returning-old-urls

I have looked at the scheduler and re-scheduled the crawler to re-index the pages.

When I try to delete the files in the Search folder, it says it can't as if it is locked.

How do I get DNN to re-index the content on the site? Is there a cache which needs to be cleared as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock is due to the the worker process accessing the files.  If recycling the app pool doesn't do it, you may have to stop the application pool in IIS and wait for the worker process to completely unload (you can kill it in TaskManager).  Then delete the files in App_Data/Search, and finally start the application pool back up.  That works for me.